# Indicar idiomas de APP HTML5 para publicar en "Windows Dev Center"

Tags: javascript, html5, windows, css3

Estoy desarrollando una *APP HTML5* con "*Intel® XDK*" y al subirla a la "*Windows Dev Denter*" indica que el idioma es "*en-US*".

Ni en las opciones del *XDK* ni en las del "*Dev Center*" veo donde editar los idiomas.
¿Como puedo indicar en que **idiomas** está la aplicación?

Edición: Otra manera de enfocarlo, XDK genera el AppxManifest.xml automáticamente, ¿Puedo indicar desde XDK parámetros del AppxManifest.xml a mano?

Comment: ¿Usas Visual Studio para desarrollar la app?

Comment: No,  estoy usando Intel® XDK

Comment: Perdón, no sé por qué he pensado que era una extensión. Sé que en Visual Studio se puede especificar el idioma en el fichero `Package.appxmanifest` pero no sé cómo estará en XDK.

Comment: Creo que se puede indicar en el archivo de configuración, un XML, pero no encuentro información al respecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he solucionado gracias a las indicaciones de [rsciriano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/602/rsciriano)

Me descargo el appx generado por el XDK, lo descomprimo con 7zip, incluyo los idiomas en el AppxManifest.xml (en la etiqueta Resources) y lo vuelvo a empaquetar con el makeappx (herramienta incluida en el visual studio comunity):

En el directório del makeappx (en  mi caso C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86):

makeappx pack /d carpeta /p salida.appx /l

Answer (score 0):

Según parece Intel XDK no permite configurar el idioma (hay varios hilos en el [foro de Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/search/site/language/en/type/forum/taxonomy_forums/45630?query=language) hablando de esto).

Lo que podrías intentar es usar [`MakeAppx.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh446767.aspx) para extraer los archivos del paquete, cambiar el `AppxManifest.xml` a mano y volver a empaquetarlo. *Igual estoy diciendo una burrada pero por probar no pierdes nada.*

Otra opción sería acceder a los archivos intermedios que genere `Intel® XDK` y empaquetar desde ahí.

De todas formas creo que por debajo se usa `Apache Cordoba` por lo que quizás ahí esté el problema, no sé si se podría cambiar algo a nivel de `Cordoba`.

También puedes cambiarte a [Ionic + Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn757057.aspx) que tiene muy buena pinta ;-)

Comment: Lo de modificar a mano el AppxManifest.xml lo he probado, pero luego el win dev center no lo acepta, ¿que tipo de compresión se usa para empaquetar?

Comment: @ArnauCastellví El empaquetado lo tendrías que hacer con `MakeAppx.exe`. De todas formas yo pediría soporte en [Dev Center](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=331509)